# Firebase user data show with delay - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, database, firebase, swiftui

Hi all I am using firebase to login in the app

Everything seems to work perfectly but I have a problem with displaying user data when logging in.

After logging in, the user is redirected to his dashboard and inside a label shows his name. I noticed that as soon as the dashboard is displayed there is a delay in displaying the user's name.

I implemented all async functions and used @MainActor specifically to avoid these delays so I can't figure out why this delay happens.

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

---

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var authManager = FirebaseAuthManager()
    
    init() { FirebaseApp.configure() }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch authManager.userStatus {
            case .undefined, .notAuthenticated :
                SignInView()
                    .environmentObject(authManager)
            case .authenticated:
                DashboardView()
                    .environmentObject(authManager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**FirebaseAuthManager.swift**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

enum AuthStatus { case undefined, notAuthenticated, authenticated }

class FirebaseAuthManager: ObservableObject {
    private let userCollection = "Users"
    @Published var userStatus: AuthStatus = .undefined
    @Published var user: FirestoreModel.User = .init (
        name: .init(firstName: "", lastName: ""),
        accountDetails: .init(emailAddress: "", uid: "")
    )
    
    init() { checkUserStatus() }
}

extension FirebaseAuthManager {
    func checkUserStatus() {
        let listener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { result, user in
            guard user != nil else { return self.userStatus = .notAuthenticated }
            self.userStatus = .authenticated
            self.fetchUserInfo(userID: user!.uid)

        }
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener)
    }
}

// MARK: - Authentication Function
    
extension FirebaseAuthManager {
    
    @MainActor
    func logout() throws {
        do { try Auth.auth().signOut() }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func signUp(email: String, password: String, name: FirestoreModel.User.Name) async throws {
        let account = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        let userInfo = FirestoreModel.User(name: .init(firstName: name.firstName, lastName: name.lastName), accountDetails: .init(emailAddress: email, uid: account.user.uid))
        let reference = Firestore.firestore()
                
        do {
            self.user = try await reference.collection(userCollection).document(account.user.uid).getDocument(as: FirestoreModel.User.self)
        } catch {
            
            if error._code == 4865 {
                try reference.collection(userCollection).document(account.user.uid).setData(from: userInfo)
                self.user = userInfo
            }
            else {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    @discardableResult
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) async throws -> AuthDataResult {
        try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
    }
}

// MARK: - Manage Data
extension FirebaseAuthManager {
func fetchUserInfo(userID: String)   {      
    let reference = Firestore.firestore().collection(self.userCollection).document(userID)
    reference.getDocument(as: FirestoreModel.User.self) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user) :
            self.user = user
        case .failure(let error) :
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

---

**Dashboard.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct DashboardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var authManager: FirebaseAuthManager

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Benvenuto " + authManager.user.name.firstName + "!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Dashboard")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Esci".uppercased()) {
                        logout()
                    }
                    .font(.callout).bold()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension DashboardView {
    private func logout() {
        Task {
            do {
                try authManager.logout()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I updated my code avoiding fetching data from `firestore` **asynchronously** so I replaced this

```
extension FirebaseAuthManager {
    @MainActor
    func fetchUserInfo(userID: String) async throws {
        let reference = Firestore.firestore()
        let path = reference.collection(userCollection).document(userID)
        self.user = try await path.getDocument(as: FirestoreModel.User.self)
    }
}
```

with this..

```
extension FirebaseAuthManager {
    func fetchUserInfo(userID: String)   {      
        let reference = Firestore.firestore().collection(self.userCollection).document(userID)
        reference.getDocument(as: FirestoreModel.User.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user) :
                self.user = user
            case .failure(let error) :
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the user logs in his name appears immediately but when I close the application and reopen it the delay in displaying the user name still seems to occur probably because he is **waiting for the user status to change from undefined to authenticated** .. How can I fix?

Comment: I believe that the issue is *when* the `DashboardView` is brought up to screen: if you immediately show that view, the data will be filled in the "Benvenuto" text after it is downloaded from Firebase. You must probably wait to show the whole view, until `userStatus` becomes `.authenticated`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " there is a delay in displaying the user's name". Given that you load the user name from Firestore and that is an asynchronous operation, a delay before it is available seems to be expected.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi i have update my question. I change my async function, but the lag issue seems to be there when the user closes the app and opens it again...

Comment: @HunterLion I've updated my question to be clearer

Comment: Loading data from a cloud resource like Firestore is always going to take time and be asynchronous. There is no fix for that. Instead your code needs to decide what to display to the user while the data is being loaded, e.g. showing "loading..." or an animation of some sort.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ah here .. now I understand .. sorry for these stupid questions .. I didn't understand the logic to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you load the user name from Firestore and that is an asynchronous operation, a delay before it is available seems to be expected.

There is no fix for that: loading data simply takes time. Your code needs to decide what to display to the user while the data is being loaded, e.g. showing "loading..." or an animation of some sort.